# Xcode 5 fails to launch app with error: failed to launch '/path/to/.app' -- Busy

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, parse-platform

I am using XCode 5, with an iPhone 5s as the dev device.  Every other time I run the app I get a pop that says "Could not launch [app name] \n busy".  My iPhone 5s then appears to crash and the only way it will respond is if I hold the home and lock button until it resets.

The application is a single view application, the only thing I have done is added the Parse.framework from [here](https://parse.com/) and used

```
[Parse setApplicationID:appID clientKey:clientKey];
[PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
```

In applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions, along with some UI that isn't hooked up to anything.

I'm not sure if this has to do with Parse or possibly the App settings.

So to be clear, the behavior is:

Fresh reset > Build and Run application on iPhone 5s > application runs fine > Build and Run application on iPhone 5s > application appears to launch but screen remains black and iPhone is no longer responsive except the screen will turn off when the lock button is pressed (but not back on) > Build and Run application on iPhone 5s > XCode says "could not launch app - busy" > hard reset iPhone

When I run this on the 64-bit simulator it works fine.

Edit 1:

I have tested with multiple applications now that we know work on multiple other devices (iPhone 5, iPhone 4, iPhone 4s) and the simulators.  I don't have another iPhone 5s so it is hard to compare exactly but everything crashes my 5s..

Comment: exactly the same problem here, such things only happen on friday.

Comment: Are you using Parse by any chance or is this a broader issue?

Comment: no, it happens if I run "Profile" when the Instruments is already running with a debugging session.

Answer (score 10):

My device was completely stuck with black screen. "To fix you have to hard reboot, holding the power and home button until the phone reboots - doesn't lose any of the data you have on your phone (a concern the first time I did it)." as stated here:

http://blog.paulhadfield.net/2014/01/iphone-hangs-when-running-from-xcode.html

For iPhone7 there is a different approach:

1. Press and hold down the power button located on the right side of
   the iPhone 7.
2. While holding down the power button, press and hold
   down the Volume Down button on the left side of the iPhone 7.

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/force-reset-iphone7-7plus/

Answer (score 3):

You were using your phone when you ran the app. Make sure you don't use your phone after you press build and run, otherwise it will be "busy"

Comment: Define 'using'.  By most definitions I've been using my phone alongside developing for iOS and it's never been a problem.  It would be fairly ridiculous if you couldn't use your phone while you were developing..

Comment: I just started to notice this while using xcode 5. Xcode 4 never had this issue. An example is: if you are reading a text while you press build and run. Just make sure you press home before pressing build and run

Answer (score 0):

Which Xcode version do you use? Same issue with Xcode 5.0.1 + iPhone 5S (iOS 7.0.4). It crashed my iPhone 5S even by the simple application created by Xcode's default project template.

It seems this issue has been fixed in Xcode 5.0.2. Xcode 5.0.2 works fine for me by now.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem for several times. It seems that this problem always happens when iCloud or other background App is running & the App I was debug is already in running mode.

My suggestion is: Avoid any background App running when debug and Make sure the App debugging is fully killed before restart a debug.

It is obvious a bug in iOS 7 + Xcode 5.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and upgrading to Xcode 5.0.2 resolved it.